# Why does Numba jit compiled function executes faster on consecutive calls to the function even after using cache=True?

Tags: python, profiling, numba

When calling a jit decorated function using numba, the first call execute slower than the later ones. This seems appropriate as first time numba will compile the function. According to numba docs, we can use `cache=True` inside jit decorator to avoid compile times. Although, even after using cache, the execution times are more or less the same for first call and faster for later calls. Why is that?

````
from numba import *
from timeit import default_timer as timer

@jit(['float64[:,:],float64[:,:]'],'(n,m),(n,m)->(n,m)',parallel=True, cache=True)
def asd(x,y):
    return x+y
u=np.random.random(1000000)
w=np.random.random(1000000)

func_start=timer()
asd(u,w)
timing=timer()-func_start
print("Function Asd 1st time: ", str(timing))

func_start=timer()
asd(u,w)
timing=timer()-func_start
print("Function Asd 2nd time: ", str(timing))```


Output:
Function Asd 1st time:  0.0036184220007271506
Function Asd 2nd time:  0.0025926230009645224

Shouldn't first time calling the function with ```cache=True``` execute it as fast as 2nd time? Why is it still executing slower? is it still compiling the function? what is happening here?
````

Comment: 1) Cache isn't working on parallel=True 2) Even if it would work, loading the cached function takes also some time. 3) If the inputs fits at least in L3 cache the second call could be faster on memory bound problems.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the L3 cache there, It makes much more sense when I pass in data larger than L3 cache size now.